# Flutter record audio in IPhone but cannot be played in Android with just_audio

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I am working on an audio recording and replaying app with Flutter, record library and just_audio library.

I record something in IOS emulator with the following code

```
await record.start(
        path: path,
        encoder: AudioEncoder.wav, // by default
        bitRate: 128000, // by default
        samplingRate: 44100, // by default
      );
```

and saved it as a `wav` file. Then I upload the file to my google drive.

After that, I run my app in Android emulator, download the file and try to play the file. I get `Source error` exception when I try to set file path for just_audio. (This works in IOS)

```
final player = AudioPlayer();

await player.setFilePath(filePath);
```

Can I please get some help? Please let me know if more code is needed.

Comment: My guess is that the WAV file was not encoded correctly.

Comment: Hi Ryan, by any chance you will know how to setup record to have the file correctly encoded? Thank you

Comment: If it's a bug in `record`, your best bet would be to check for existing bug reports, existing pull request, and in the absence of any, submit your own bug report.